# Fabric.js: How to observe object:scaling event and update properties dynamically?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to get the shape properties to dynamically update when the shape is being scaled.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anirudhrantsandraves/DAjrp/

The console log commands:

```
console.log('Width =  '+scaledObject.currentWidth);
console.log('Height = '+scaledObject.currentHeight);
```

are supposed to dynamically display the height and width of the shape as it is being scaled.

The properties remain the same in the console when the shape gets scaled. However, when I select the object again and scale it, the previous values of the properties are displayed.

Is there a way to make this dynamic?

Comment: you need to use  other events to track details dynamically..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are used to get the current width and height in Fabric.js.

So in "object:scaling" event:

```
canvas.on('object:scaling', onObjectScaled);

function onObjectScaled(e)
{
    var scaledObject = e.target;
    console.log('Width =  '+scaledObject.getWidth());
    console.log('Height = '+scaledObject.getHeight());
}
```

will serve your purpose.

Updated fiddle — http://jsfiddle.net/DAjrp/2/

Comment: I am facing another issue when I try to track object properties upon scaling and moving. I push my created shapes to a global array and observe object:modified event. The scaling and moving go way off when I do them. Code in the next comment.

Comment: canvas.on('object:modified', onObjectModified);

function onObjectModified(e)
{
 var xScale, yScale, ht, wd, rad, oID, i, tp, lf;

 var modifiedObject = e.target;

 xScale = modifiedObject.get('scaleX');
 yScale = modifiedObject.get('scaleY');
 wd = modifiedObject.get('width');
 ht = modifiedObject.get('height');
 rad = modifiedObject.get('width')/2;
 oID = modifiedObject.get('identifier');
 lf = modifiedObject.get('left');
 tp = modifiedObject.get('top');
 for (i = 0; i < canvasObjs.length; i++)
 {
  (contd. in next comment)

Comment: if (canvasObjs[i].identifier === oID)
  { 
   canvasObjs[i].left = lf;
   canvasObjs[i].top = tp;
   console.log(canvasObjs[i].left);
   console.log(canvasObjs[i].top);
   if (canvasObjs[i].type === 'Rectangle')
   {
    canvasObjs[i].width = xScale*wd;
    canvasObjs[i].height = yScale*ht;
    console.log(canvasObjs[i].width);
    console.log(canvasObjs[i].height);
   }
   else if (canvasObjs[i].type === 'Circle')
   {
    canvasObjs[i].width = xScale*rad;
    console.log(canvasObjs[i].width);
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: please provide a fiddle so that it will be easy to understand what the problem is

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong actually. I was multiplying the width/ height with the scale factor. Fixed it :)

Comment: is this still valid for FabricJS 2.0? I'm having `getWidth` is not a function error on 2.0. I couldn't find a alternative in the doc as well. Please advice.

Comment: @Tharanga and others struggling like I just was: Fabric has replaced `object.getWidth` and `object.getHeight` with `object.getScaledWidth` and `object.getScaledHeight()` in version two, as described here: http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if you wanted to get the scaled height

```
canvas.on("object:scaling", (e) => {
    canvas.getActiveObjects().forEach((o) => {
        // if it's scaled then just multiple the height by scaler
        const objHeight = o.scaleY ? o.height * o.scaleY : o.height;
        // ...
    });
});
```